# How to handle Internet Explorer start message using WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The popup which has "Welcome to IE8" message, "Next" and "Ask me later" buttons. So how could I handle this using WebDriver? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of it manually. Open up IE outside of Selenium, run through the set up. Once it's done for that user, it won't be appearing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings can be controlled through the registry. Selenium WebDriver offers the [`WindowsUtils`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.html) API to manipulate the Windows registry.

- [`writeBooleanRegistryValue(java.lang.String key, boolean data)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.html#writeBooleanRegistryValue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)
- [`writeIntRegistryValue(java.lang.String key, int data)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.html#writeIntRegistryValue%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (for DWORD values)
- [`writeStringRegistryValue(java.lang.String key, java.lang.String data)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.html#writeStringRegistryValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

According to [How to Disable Internet Explorer 8 Welcome Screen (Tour and RunOnce) for All Users](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-ie8-tour-welcome-screen-runonce-all-users/) (whose instructions I've used last year), the following registry values must be set:

```
=Value Name=                   =Data=   =Type=
IE8RunOnceLastShown            1        REG_DWORD
IE8RunOncePerInstallCompleted  1        REG_DWORD
IE8RunOnceCompletionTime       (empty)  REG_BINARY
IE8TourShown                   1        REG_DWORD
IE8TourShownTime               (empty)  REG_BINARY
IE8RunOnceLastShown_TIMESTAMP  (empty)  REG_BINARY
```

In Java code, it would be something like this:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsUtils;
...
    WindowsUtils.writeIntRegistryValue("IE8RunOnceLastShown", 1);
    WindowsUtils.writeIntRegistryValue("IE8RunOncePerInstallCompleted", 1);
    WindowsUtils.writeStringRegistryValue("IE8RunOnceCompletionTime", "");
    WindowsUtils.writeIntRegistryValue("IE8TourShown", 1);
    WindowsUtils.writeStringRegistryValue("IE8TourShownTime", "");
    WindowsUtils.writeStringRegistryValue("IE8RunOnceLastShown", "");
```

Comment: Just aware of the existence of this class. Is this only in Java binding?

Comment: @user1177636 A quick grep in the source code shows that it's only [implemented in Java](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.java). It launches an external command to manipulate the registry. This method is language-independent, so one can write a similar method for other languages.